# C++ ampersand '&' at the end of member function declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm sorry I couldn't come with a better title.

What the last ampersand `&` means in the following code snippet:

```
A & A::operator=(A rhs) &
{
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Depending on the answer I would like to know if:

- it makes sense only for `operator=` or can also be applied to any function
- it is a new C++11 feature or if it already exists in C++98/03

If you need more context, I found this syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653520/951426

There is a small explanation but I don't understand.

Edit (formatting and short answer to my questions):

- it's not specific to `operator=`
- it is a new C++11 feature necessary due to the new rvalues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this#

Comment: Thanks, that answer my question(s). Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: I think you dont't have to feel sorry, as this duplicate is not obvious at all. Others looking for the meaning of "'&' at the end of member function declaration" will not easily find the linked question.

Comment: Anybody mind explaining why this was reopened?

Comment: @GuillaumePapin and thanks for getting the destructor fixed on that existing answer. This is how SO content improves by avoiding duplicates!