# error in reference qualifier

Tags: c++, constants, qualifiers

Why I cant define this function,

```
int *clone() const &
{ 
    return new int(10); 
}
```

or

```
int x;
int *clone() const &&
{ 
    return new int(std::move(x)) ; 
}
```

I should be able to add const qualifier functions. Should I include any headers?

Comment: What's the `&` and `&&` supposed to do there?

Comment: What Luchian Grigore said. Also, if x is a member variable and clone() a const method, std::move(x) would violate const-correctness if allowed to compile (because it would allow modifying x).

Comment: and instead of returning a pointer to an int, its probably better to return the int itself

Comment: Its not the actual function, the actual is a big class,rather than int, I just simplified because problem is in qualifiers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: well you should open the C++ standard then. cf my comment to doctorlove's reply.

Comment: @v.oddou any C++ question can be answered with "open the C++ standard", so why bother posting on SO if you can't ask questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the r-value reference on parameters, for example in a move assignment or move constructor.
It seems clang has been trying an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this) called 'called "rvalue reference for *this"', but I suggest you work through the [move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651063/the-efficient-way-to-write-move-copy-and-move-assignment-constructors) constructors and assignment operators first.

Comment: C++11 clearly specifies the ref-qualifier on functions. see `8.3.5 [dcl.fct]`. [gcc support](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-04/msg00024.html). You all need to give OP a break.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to c++ and I am in the same error with you.
I compiled the sample code, from C++ Primer 5th Edition, which described the reference qualifier. However, my GNU compiler showed me error. I suppose that current compilers do not support this new feature introduced in C++11. And it seems not many people know this because very few information can be found on the Internet. Maybe later compilers will support this feature.

Many c++11 features haven't been supported... I've met some before.

This is part of the sample code, similar to yours:

```
Foo sorted() &&;
Foo sorted() const &
```

Answer (score 0):

Because any qualifier after function name applies to this pointer. 
if you want to make constant this pointer
you should just do overloading  by : int *clone() const

Comment: So when do I use reference qualifiers?

Comment: @TamimAdDari after function name? NEVER

Comment: @kassak is right 

you cant overload function using eference qualifiers AFTER the funcvtion name , that is this pointer